# Erro ao inicializar o Rstudio

Tags: r

Ao inicializar o Rstudio me deparo com o seguinte `"ERROR"`, relacionado aos pacotes `"manipulate"` e `"rstudio"`:

```
Error installing package: * installing *source* package 'rstudio' ...
Aviso em file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'D:/Users/Marcos/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rstudio/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  não é possível abrir a conexão
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'rstudio'
* removing 'D:/Users/Marcos/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rstudio'

Error installing package: * installing *source* package 'manipulate' ...
Aviso em file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'D:/Users/Marcos/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/manipulate/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  não é possível abrir a conexão
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'manipulate'
* removing 'D:/Users/Marcos/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/manipulate'
```

Alguém saber dizer como evitar esse `"ERROR"` ?

Comment: Por acaso você mexeu em algum arquivo `.Rprofile`? O erro acontece apenas no RStudio, mas não no RGui ou pelo prompt?

Comment: Já tentou desinstalar e reinstalar o Rstudio?

Comment: Veja se isto lhe ajuda...Aparentemente é algu problema de permissão de usuário. A segunda resposta neste link, diz para vocês copiar a pasta dos pacotes que estão com problema (manipulate e rstudio) do diretorio do RStudio, geralmente "C:\Program Files\RStudio\R\library" e colar na pasta do seu usuario "D:/Users/Marcos/Documents/R/win-library/"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517058/error-starting-r-studio-for-the-first-time